# Only one change to be made

Tags: mathematics

Your objective is to change one constant in the following equation so that it equates to true.

Rules:

- No changing the equals sign.
- The numbers are correct.
- There only needs to be one change in order to make the equation true.

> 142 / 2930 = 142

Comment: The tag is substitution, so the "change" should be to replace something, and since the numbers are correct and I can't touch the equals sign, that only leaves the divisor, no? Or are the numbers correct, just in the wrong positions?

Comment: Well, i do believe this has been made too simple.

Comment: Define constant

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change

> the division operator (`/`) to the modulo operator (`%`)

The resulting equation

> 142 % 2930 = 142

is certainly true.

Answer (score 8):

If you can move up the 0 to become an exponent, you get:

$$
142 / 239^0 = 142
$$

This works since $239^0 = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different answer just to add on:

> The division symbol could be moved over top of 2930 to appear as a strikethrough. If this is done, $142=142$ with some extra numbers that had to be crossed out and are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can also replace the space after / by a second /
You then have 142 with a line comment, which, when casted into a boolean gives true as it is a nonzero number